# Creating a table in Mysql using VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub Add_Tab()
        Dim createSql As String
        Try
            con = New MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)
            con.Open()
            Dim tblname = TextBox2.Text

            createSql = "CREATE TABLE " & tblname & " (CODE VARCHAR(25), PCID VARCHAR(25), Assigned_To TEXT, Deployed TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (CODE));"
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(createSql, con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
```

Hi Guys, i got this code which is set to create a table in mysql, however its giving me an error[image]

Comment: My guess: `tblname` is an empty string. Debug your code and see for yourself

Comment: nope i only have 2 textbox and both are filled in when i tried

Comment: maybemy declarations on the "class" has something to do with it?  `Dim myConnectionString = "server=********; user id=*****; password=******; database=*****"
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)`

Comment: And what is `createSql` right before executing?

Comment: Show the output for `Debug.Print createSql`

Comment: `Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll `are you referring to this @Akina?

Comment: Set breakpoint on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Start your code. When stopped, then open Immediate window (Ctrl-G, it seems), type `? createSql<Enter>`, provide the output.

Comment: @JannelynMorales: You create a query with the content: `CREATE TABLE ...` Let us see what that query looks like after you put in the tablename from the textbox.

Comment: `error BC30454: Expression is not a method.` here you go @akina

Comment: @JannelynMorales: What we need from you is the content of `createSql`. It starts with `CREATE TABLE` :-)

Comment: @juergend `"CREATE TABLE " & tblname & " (CODE VARCHAR(25), PCID VARCHAR(25), Assigned_To TEXT, Deployed TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (CODE))`

Comment: @JannelynMorales: We need the actual value when the program is running and putting in the value from the textbox. To get that you have to pause your program there and read the value or print it out. I think it would be better if you take a tutorial on debugging. It is essential for programming

Comment: will do, thanks for the recommendation

Comment: Got it, if i change the `" & tblname & "` to a default name, it works however i need to use the text entered on textbox2 to be the name of the table. i tried directly using `" & TextBox2.Text &" ` but doesnt work. can tou help me with this one please?

Comment: Upon debugging, found out that the value of textbox2.text returns as two double quotes ("") can you help me please?

Comment: got it! i just reaize i declared textbox 1 & 2 = "" on the click event urggghhh!! all good now guys